# Silverlight: bind command of a generic component

Tags: silverlight, mvvm

I have a problem.

I created a generic container that I use in my application.
This container exports two properties (for now): its content and a button action.

The problem is that I can't bind the action.

The generic container has a button:

```
<HyperlinkButton x:Name="expandButton" Width="16">
```

In the code behind I export a ICommand property:

```
public ICommand ExpandCommand 
        {
            get { return Click.GetCommand(expandButton); }
            set { Click.SetCommand(expandButton, value); }
        }
```

And, when I trie to use it:

```
<abo:DashBoardPanel Margin="10" Grid.Row="1" Title="Command Panel"
                                    DataContext="{Binding Commands}"
                                    ExpandCommand="{Binding test}"
                                    >
```

When the component (the one which uses the generic container) is allocated the following exception fires:

> {System.ArgumentException: Un oggetto di tipo
>   'System.Windows.Data.Binding' non può essere convertito nel tipo
>   'System.Windows.Input.ICommand'.    su
>   System.RuntimeType.TryChangeType(Object value, Binder binder,
>   CultureInfo culture, Boolean needsSpecialCast)    su
>   System.RuntimeType.CheckValue(Object value, Binder binder, CultureInfo
>   culture, BindingFlags invokeAttr)    su
>   System.Reflection.MethodBase.CheckArguments(Object[] parameters,
>   Binder binder, BindingFlags invokeAttr, CultureInfo culture, Signature
>   sig)    su System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj,
>   BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters,
>   CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)    su
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   su System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.SetValue(Object obj, Object
>   value, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] index,
>   CultureInfo culture)    su
>   System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.SetValue(Object obj, Object
>   value, Object[] index)    su
>   MS.Internal.XamlMemberInfo.SetValue(Object target, Object value)    su
>   MS.Internal.XamlManagedRuntimeRPInvokes.SetValue(XamlTypeToken inType,
>   XamlQualifiedObject& inObj, XamlPropertyToken inProperty,
>   XamlQualifiedObject& inValue)}

(It's italian.. the translation is something like "An object of type 'System.Windows.Data.Binding' cannot be converted into 'System.Windows.Input.ICommand')

Any ideas?

Thank you.
Francesco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think ExpandCommand needs to be a dependency property to be able to bind to it.  At least from what you've shown, that is the first place I would start editing.

ExpandCommand would look like this in your generic class:

```
      public static readonly DependencyProperty ExpandCommandProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register(
       "ExpandCommand",
       typeof(ICommand),
       typeof(genericobject),
       new PropertyMetadata(OnExpandCommandChanged));

    public ICommand ExpandCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return (ICommand)this.GetValue(ExpandCommandProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue(ExpandCommandProperty, value);
        }
    }
    private static void OnExpandCommandChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        genericobject picker = (genericobject)d;
        if (picker == null)
            return;

    }
```

Comment: Thank you. It works! I thought I needed to register a dependency property only if I wanted my UI to remain updated with the model